# If I have an array of 5 elements lets say (1,2,3,4,5) how do create a new one with double each integer?

Tags: java, arrays

If I have an array of of elements how do I create one a new array of the same size where each integer in the array is twice the value then in the previous array - i.e. old array { 1 , 2 , 3 } the new array = { 2 , 4 ,6 }

The program below takes in an integer between 3 and 10 and outputs an array starting at 1 upto the element they put in so if they enter 5 an array is created that is {1,2,3,4,5}

I'm not sure how to create a new array from an old one.

```
public class Arraya {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.print("Enter a number of rows between 3 and 10 ");

    Scanner rowScan = new Scanner(System.in);
   int rowInput = rowScan.nextInt();
   int[] numberArray = new int[rowInput];
   for(int i =0;i< rowInput;i++) 
    { numberArray[i] = i+1 ;

    }
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numberArray));
```

}
}

Comment: what have you tried so far? you are confusing us with your expected answer and the whole thing. Can you start solving the problem and when you have a problem come back for help

Comment: 6 is not double of 1, and neither is 7 the double of 2. Only 10 is the double of 5.

Comment: Sorry I've developed the problem

Comment: Once again, 4 is not the double of 1 and 5 is not the double of 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want values in a new array, then

```
int[] array ={1,2,3,4,5};
int arrayLength = array.size();
int[] array2 = new int[arrayLength];
for(int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++)
{
    array2[i] = array[i]*2;
}
```

If you want values doubles in the same array, then

```
int[] array ={1,2,3,4,5};
for(int i=0; i<array.size(); i++)
{
   array[i]*=2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If and only if I am interpreting your question correctly, you want to double each value of your array. That iswhat I gather from this question.

go through your array using a for loop and multiply each element by 2.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using Java 8 stream.

```
Integer[] intValues =  new Integer [] {1,2,3,4,5};      
Integer[] outputValues = Arrays.stream(intValues).map(i ->    (i*2)).toArray(Integer[] :: new);
Arrays.stream(outputValues).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```